# PhpStorm run cmd on save

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm, php-cs-fixer

I have an environment under Windows 11 with WSL and Docker. I use PhpStorm. My projects use phpfmt.

I would like when I save any file to run `composer fmt` command based on php-cs-fixer.

My project is in a WSL folder.

In PhpStorm settings ("Tools | File Watcher") I've added a new configuration on PHP files with Program: `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\www\mywebsite\vendor\bin\php-cs-fixer.bat`, no arguments, no output

And in "PHP | Quality Tools" I've added a PHP CS Fixer configuration with `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\www\mywebsite\vendor\bin\php-cs-fixer.bat`.

But when I click on "Validate" in my Quality Tools configuration, I get a message "Can not run PHP CS Fixer"

How do I do what I want?

Comment: Please try to configure a WSL-based PHP CLI interpreter first and then use a remote code quality tool configuration:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-php-cs-fixer.html#configure-php-cs-fixer-script-associated-with-php-interpreter

Comment: @duck_in_hat thanks, I did that but now when I made a mistake, I have a little bulb, it doesn't fix automatically. And if I click on the bulb and corrected, if I run a composer fmt, there are always differences. For example I have an array 
[
'#000',
'#fff'
]
The bulb suggest to convert to an array with array(....) or put the elements on the same line. But if I run a composer fmt, it puts my array back as before but adds a comma after the last element of the array